# sending a personalized packet in ns-3

Tags: ns-3

I want to create a packet with additional data and then sending it using an on/off application in ns-3. I saw that I can only precise the size of packets and the rate. Can you please tell me how can I send a particular packet?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can edit the ns-3 framework in order to create a particular packet that follow your specifics. Then, the packet will be sent as a normal one.